# django many-to-many relationships: how to remove items but not delete them from related Models

Tags: django, django-models

Django Newbie question.  I have the following model:

```
class Leg(models.Model):
  drive_date = models.DateField()
  startpoint = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  endpoint = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  start_time = models.TimeField()
  riders = models.ManyToManyField(Rider, blank=True)
  drivers = models.ManyToManyField(Driver, blank=True)
  carpool = models.ForeignKey(Carpool,  blank=True, null=True)
```

for certain instances of Leg, I want to remove any existing riders and drivers from the Leg model, but NOT delete them from the Rider or Driver Models (not shown) respectively.   Can't figure out how to do it.  When I iterate with:

```
for driver in leg.drivers.all():
    driver.delete()
```

It appears to delete the actual Driver object, which I don't want to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I might approach this would be to create a custom manager for the Driver model.  Untested code below:

```
from django.db import models

class DriverManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(DriverManager, self).get_query_set().filter(removed=False)

class Driver(models.Model):
    # new stuff to add ...
    removed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = models.Manager()  # default manager
    active = DriverManager()  # custom manager
```

Explanation: A new field, `removed`, is added to the Driver model.  Instead of deleting the record, you set it to True and save.  Then, where you would normally filter Driver.objects, use Driver.active instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  It seems that in the example you provide, the Driver would either be "removed" or "not removed", which would apply for all legs. But I need the driver to be removed only for certain instances of Leg, but still there for other instances, so I'm not sure if it would work.  But I will give it a try.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to selectively remove drivers from the leg, but not delete them.

In your case just assign leg.drivers = None, then leg.save().

Comment: Thanks again.  I assumed it was something simple.

Answer (score 12):

The correct code to remove the items from the relationship is:

```
for driver in leg.drivers.all():
    leg.drivers.remove( driver )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
leg.drivers.clear()

.clear() to completely remove completely(efficiently)
.remove(<related obj>) to remove one relation
.remove([<related obj>, <related obj>...]) to remove one or more relation
```